# Como mudar a linguagem do natbib no LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Estou a realizar a minha tese de mestrado em LaTeX, e estou utilizando o `natbib` com o `mendeley` para fazer a bibliografia. No entanto, a bibliografia final aparece em inglês. 
Existe alguma forma de alterar a linguagem padrão do `natbib` ou só com o package `biblatex`?

---

Quando eu uso esses comandos aparece-me o erro:"Package biblatex Error: File "  ".bbl' not created by biblatex. \begin{document}".
Além de que eu uso alguns comandos do natbib como o \citep e o \citealt que eu creio que não funcionam com o biblatex, mas não encontro o correspondente no documento de informação do package.

Comment: Na rede tem essa [comunidade](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) que é mais especifica para tratar assuntos sobre `Latex`.Em meu `TCC` eu usei o [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) que por sinal me atendeu muito bem.

Answer (score 1):

Boa pergunta. Eu consigo alterar a linguagem utilizando BibLaTeX. Abaixo seguem meus arquivos .tex e .bib mínimos para obter o mesmo resultado que eu. Primeiramente, mostro o arquivo .tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\bibliography{bibliografia} 

\begin{document}

Este texto cita o livro de \cite{Nelder1989}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

O conteúdo do arquivo `bibliografia.bib` é o seguinte:

```
@book{Nelder1989,
  address = {London},
  author = {McCullagh, P. and Nelder, J. A.},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/21236b0d4dcf920ff44d2c578d82bd780/vivion},
  date = {(1989)},
  interhash = {57a5eea9902828a90b76e8e38a420073},
  intrahash = {1236b0d4dcf920ff44d2c578d82bd780},
  keywords = {generalized glm linear models statistics},
  location = {London, UK: Chapman \& Hall / CRC},
  publisher = {Chapman \& Hall / CRC},
  timestamp = {2010-01-10T01:48:50.000+0100},
  title = {Generalized Linear Models},
  year = 1989
}
```

Meu resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que seria necessário ajustar as configurações das citações para que se adequem ao estilo da tua tese ou dissertação.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com um problema: Quando inseria a citação em um artigo em português, ele mantinha a separação de múltiplos autores com o "and" ao invés de "e". Por exemplo:
"Segundo Salsbury and Mhas-kar (2013)..." ao invés de "Salsbury e Mhas-kar (2013)".
A solução foi mudar a função dentro do arquivo <nome_do_arquivo_main>.bst, conforme a imagem. Talvez a solução ajude outros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]