# Como fazer uma citação em português?

Tags: latex, bibtex

Estou tendo um problema para realizar citações de referências bibliográficas em português, pois quando tenho uma referência com 2 autores no bibtex, como no exemplo abaixo

```
@book{Hubral_80,
  author =   {Hubral, P. and Krey, T.},
  year =     {1980},
  title =    {Interval Velocities from Seismic Reflection Traveltime Measurements},
  publisher =    {Society of Exploration Geophysicists},
  volume =   {},
  number =   {},
  pages =    {203}
}
```

e tento fazer a citação da mesma usando `\citet{Hubral_80}`, obtenho apenas a citação em inglês, ou seja, Hubral and Krey (1980).

Ressalto que no arquivo .bib utilizo "and" para separar os nomes dos autores, pois só desta forma o tex entende como sendo dois autores de fato. Se tento colocar um "e" para separar os autores, nas referências aparece corretamente, mas na citação aparece apenas o primeiro autor.

Há alguma forma de aparecer Hubral e Krey (1980) na citação e referência?

Comment: Esse `citet{}` é de algum pacote, né? Isso deve ser definido nele mesmo...

Comment: Não encontrei nenhum pacote voltado para isso diretamente. Pelo menos não que eu saiba. Os pacotes que estou usando são os seguintes: utf8 {inputenc};[brazilian]{babel};[T1]{fontenc};{aeguill};{helvetic};{fancyheadings};{graphicx} 
;[all]{xy} ; {scalefnt}; {amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}; {float};{amssymb}; {amsmath};{amsfonts};{amssymb};{amsthm};{amscd}.

Comment: Esse post abaixo respondeu a minha pergunta! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/457130/317669